# program stopped working when I'm trying to input

Tags: c++, class, input

I'm working on a project, to create a linked list in class but I can't even start working on it because every time I run the program it's will stop working when I want to input data.

Can someone tell me how to input data properly using class? and if possible please let me know how to improve this program. The code that I've done is quite long.

I'll try to make it short and simple for you guys to understand. A lot of people been suggesting me to use `std::string` but our lecturer never mentioned about it so we have no idea how to use it.

If I have to use it that means I have to start learn it from the beginning which means it will take time for me to really understand it.

We're also required to have a function where we can update the data stored, search the data based on one of its data and make a summary for it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//CLASS USED IN PROGRAM
class carInsurance
{
    private:
        int total;
        int customerNo;
        string name;
        string iCno;
        char dob[10];
        string nationality;
        string address;
        char phoneNo[15];
        string email;
        string occupation;

        char carNo[10];
        char expireDate[11];
        float insuranceAmount;
        char carUsage[30];
        char manufacturingDate[11];

        int package;
        int option;
        int additional;
        int noCustomer[10];

    public:
        void add();
        void presetdata();
        static void deleteFunc(carInsurance noCustomer[]);
        static void viewAll(carInsurance noCustomer[]);


    //constructor name has to be the same as class
    carInsurance(int carInsurance_total,
                int carInsurance_customerNo,
                string carInsurance_name,
                string carInsurance_iCno,
                char carInsurance_dob[10],
                string carInsurance_nationality,
                string carInsurance_address,
                char carInsurance_phoneNo[15],
                string carInsurance_email,
                string carInsurance_occupation,

                char carInsurance_carNo[10],
                char carInsurance_expireDate[11],
                float carInsurance_insuranceAmount,
                char carInsurance_carUsage[30],
                char carInsurance_manufacturingDate[11],

                int carInsurance_package,
                int carInsurance_option,
                int carInsurance_additional)
    {
        total = carInsurance_total;
        customerNo = carInsurance_customerNo;
        name = carInsurance_name;
        iCno = carInsurance_iCno;
        dob[10] = carInsurance_dob[10];
        nationality = carInsurance_nationality;
        address = carInsurance_address;
        phoneNo[15] = carInsurance_phoneNo[15];
        email = carInsurance_email;
        occupation = carInsurance_occupation;
        carNo[10] = carInsurance_carNo[10];
        expireDate[11] = carInsurance_expireDate[11];
        insuranceAmount = carInsurance_insuranceAmount;
        carUsage[30] = carInsurance_carUsage[30];
        manufacturingDate[11] = carInsurance_manufacturingDate[11];
        package = carInsurance_package;
        option = carInsurance_option;
        additional = carInsurance_additional;
    } // end of constructor

    carInsurance()
    { // Set all variables to null

        total = 0;
        customerNo = 0;
        name = " ";
        iCno = " ";
        dob[10] = '\0';
        nationality = " ";
        address = " ";
        phoneNo[15] = '\0';
        email = " ";
        occupation = " ";
        carNo[10] = '\0';
        expireDate[11] = '\0';
        insuranceAmount = 0;
        carUsage[30] = '\0';
        manufacturingDate[11] = '\0';

        package = 0;
        option = 0;
        additional = 0;
    }

    // SET
    void setChar(char carInsurance_dob[10],
                char carInsurance_phoneNo[15],
                char carInsurance_carNo[10],
                char carInsurance_expireDate[10],
                char carInsurance_carUsage[30],
                char carInsurance_manufacturingDate[10])
    {dob[10] = carInsurance_dob[10];
     phoneNo[15] = carInsurance_phoneNo[15];
     carNo[10] = carInsurance_carNo[10];
     expireDate[11] = carInsurance_expireDate[11];
     carUsage[30] = carInsurance_carUsage[30];
     manufacturingDate[11] = carInsurance_manufacturingDate[11];}

    void setname(string carInsurance_name){name = carInsurance_name;}
    void setiCno(string carInsurance_iCno){iCno = carInsurance_iCno;}
    void setAddress(string carInsurance_address){address = carInsurance_address;}
    void setString(string carInsurance_nationality, string carInsurance_email,string carInsurance_occupation)
    {nationality = carInsurance_nationality; email = carInsurance_email; occupation = carInsurance_occupation;}
    void setInt(int carInsurance_total, int carInsurance_customerNo, int carInsurance_package, int carInsurance_option, int carInsurance_additional)
        {customerNo = carInsurance_customerNo; package = carInsurance_package; option = carInsurance_option; additional = carInsurance_additional;}
    void setFloat (float carInsurance_insuranceAmount){insuranceAmount = carInsurance_insuranceAmount;}

    // GET
    string getname(){return name;}
    string getiCno(){return iCno;}
    string getaddress(){return address;}
    string getString(){return nationality; return email; return occupation;}
    int getInt(){return total; return customerNo; return package; return option; return additional;}
    float getFloat(){return insuranceAmount;}
}; //end class
```

Here goes my main:

```cpp
//function declaration
//to prevent overload run function outside
void add();


//THE MAIN FUNCTION OF PROGRAM
int main()
{
    carInsurance obj; // obj is class object
    carInsurance *noCustomer[10];
    int choice;


    while(choice != 4)
    {
        cout << "1. ADD, UPDATE, DELETE\n" << "2. SEARCH\n" << "3. VIEW ALL\n" << "4. SUMMARY REPORT\n" << "5. EXIT\n" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        system("cls");

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                cout << "___________________________________\n";
                cout << "\n\tADD/UPDATE/DELETE\n";
                cout << "___________________________________\n";

                cout << "\n1. ADD\n2. UPDATE\n3. DELETE\n" << endl;
                cin >> choice;
                system("cls");

                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        int i;
                        int total = 0;
                        cout << "How many customer? ";
                        cin >> total;
                        for(i=0; i<total; ++i)
                        {
                            cout << "________________________________\n";
                            cout << "\n\tCUSTOMER NO. " << 1 + i;
                            cout << "\n________________________________\n";
                            noCustomer[i]->add();  // this is function call to input

                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    case 2:
                    {
                        int paymentID;
                        //cout << "UPDATE" << endl;
                        cout << "\nEnter the customer ID that you want to update:";
                        cin >> paymentID;
                        // function here
                        break;
                    }

                    case 3:
                    {
                        int paymentID;
                        //cout << "DELETE" << endl;
                        cout << "\nEnter the customer ID that you want to delete:";
                        cin >> paymentID;
                        noCustomer[10]->deleteFunc(noCustomer[10]);

                        break;
                    }

                } // End of switch case for add,update,delete
                system("cls");
                break;
            } // End of case 1

            case 2:
            {
                cout << "___________________________\n";
                cout << "\n\t  SEARCH\n";
                cout << "___________________________\n";

                system("pause");
                system("cls");

                break;
            }

            case 3:
            {   cout << "___________________________\n";
                cout << "\n\tVIEW ALL\n";
                cout << "___________________________\n";
                obj.presetdata();
                noCustomer[10]->viewAll(noCustomer[10]);
                cout<<"\n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            }

            case 4:
            {
                cout << "___________________________\n";
                cout << "\n\tSUMMARY REPORT\n";
                cout << "___________________________\n\n";
                cout << "1. Sorted by different month\n2. Sorted by different car type\n3. Sorted by different insurance" << endl;
                cin >> choice;

                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    case 2:
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    case 3:
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    default:
                        cout << "Wrong input! Please choose again: ";
                        cin >> choice;
                        system("pause");
                }

                break;
            }

            case 5:{
                cout << "___________________________\n";
                cout << "\n\tTHANK YOU!\t\n";
                cout << "___________________________";
                exit(0); }

            default:
                continue;
        }// End of switch case

    }// End of while

    return 0; //indicates success
}//End of main
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think (not saying that in a condescending manner) that taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will help you maximize your chances of getting an answer. Right now, your question i a bit vague, the answers can be opinion-based, and also, you're expecting people who answer you to read this whole block and improve it for you. So... Not saying wont happen, but you can make your question much better and also useful for the site.

Comment: Fyi, `noCustomer[10]-> ...` is a *bad* idea. That pointer array is only 10 elements wide, so only index-defined from `0...9`. You're accessing out of bounds and incurring *undefined behavior*. Unrelated. I don't see a single input validation in this entire code wall, so if that is part of the assignment, you have a considerable task ahead.

Comment: `char` arrays are not copied using `=` but with a `strcpy` function. If you use `std::string` everywhere, you can avoid this problem.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide just the code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Too much code is just as bad as too little.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**.

Comment: Be careful about [posting about **your** timeline requirements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/177800), making it other people's problem that you have a [deadline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/177800) is not very well received. It draws down votes like crazy and can put off many of the more experienced community members from posting any answer at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a problem in the inner switch statement:

```
case 1:
{
    int i;
    int total = 0;
    cout << "How many customer? ";
    cin >> total;
    for(i=0; i<total; ++i)
    {
        cout << "________________________________\n";
        cout << "\n\tCUSTOMER NO. " << 1 + i;
        cout << "\n________________________________\n";
        noCustomer[i]->add();  // this is function call to input
        break;
    }
}

case 2:
```

The `break` operator breaks the loop, but does not prevent executing `case 2:` branch.

Yet another problem: re-assignment of `choice`. User may input 4 in any input request that will break `while (choice != 4)` unexpectedly. You can avoid troubles with `break` and re-assignments by using functions.

There is a lot of out of array bounds access by indexes that are equal to array sizes.

It is not clear what you want to reach in `dob[10] = carInsurance_dob[10];` It copies 11th char. Maybe you want to copy the whole char array. Use `std::string` for error-free code.